# What's the right phrase for a special return value that indicates failure?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

With methods such as java.lang.String.indexOf, which finds the position of the first occurrence of a characters, the return value is a "nonsensical" value such as -1 when the search fails. What is the correct term for such a special value? I find myself wanting to call them "sentinel values" but that's not quite right.

What I want to capture is the idea that it is an instance of the return type but a special value that can easily be distinguished (e.g. by being less than zero or equal to null).

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Failure value" is self-explanatory, and has at least some prior usage.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's called an error code.

Comment: It clearly is an error code. But I want to capture the idea that, like a sentinel value, it is an ordinary and legitimate member of the normal return type (e.g. int) but easily distinguished from a normal return (e.g. less than zero).

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of it as an example of [in-band signaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-band_signaling).

Comment: In band-signalling might use this trick. Or it could simply use a separate flag field to distinguish the states (i.e. it serializes a type union). I am looking for the correct terminology to discuss these different techniques. Thank you for the comment though.